# What is the best way to Join on an Inline tablue-valued function?

Tags: sql, function, sqlperformance

I have the SQL code below, is it the cleanest way to reference a inline tablue valued function in a Join? It looks a little ugly so I wasn't sure and couldn't find anything while googling. There's actually a lot more joins that are like this, this is just a single example.

You can see my "(Select * from INlinefunction (parameter))" for each join.

The report was having some performance issues so I re-wrote a scalar function to inline table-valued

Thanks

```
FROM   table1 SAV
   LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 REL
         ON SAV.SBACCT = REL.RXACCT
   LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 RMX
         ON (SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_ITV_TrimLeadingZeros (REL.RMKEY)) = (SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_ITV_TrimLeadingZeros (RMX.RXKEY))
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT SFACCT
                    FROM   table4
                    WHERE  SFAPPL = 'RM'
                           AND SFFNAM IN ( 'UF0015'))UDF
         ON (SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_ITV_TrimLeadingZeros (RMX.RXKEY)) = (SELECT * FROM dbo.udf_ITV_TrimLeadingZeros (UDF.SFACCT))
WHERE  SAV.SBACTP IN ( '275')
   AND Isnull(UDF.SFACCT, 'X') = 'X'
```

Comment: What are you doing with the tvf?  It looks to me, based on the name, like you are trimming leading 0s, which certainly doesn't require a custom function.

Comment: which db you are using ??'

Comment: It is only trimming leading 0s. It's an old microsoft SQL server 2008 R2. It's going to be upgraded in the next 6 months because it's out of support. I am still curious about the question though.

Comment: Well, you don't need the function in 2008 either.  But if you needed to use the function, I would use the function inside a derived table, and join on the output of that.

Comment: Thanks Andrew- what is the built in 2008 function? I can't find it. Or are you saying to use inline SQL without a function?  I do like your suggestion of a derived table and just Cross Applying in there instead, it does look a little cleaner. I think i will go with that option.